Apache2 only loads indexof or 404 when i try to open a other site (Cloudflare, Ubuntu)
I am trying to set my webpage in apache2.
When I try to open a .html file through the browser line (example: https://example.com/index.html), it only shows the standard 404 Page of Apache2.
My site config:
/etc/apache2/sites-aviable/000-default.conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAdmin it@example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <IfModule mod_dir.c>
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
        </IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

And the structure of the /var/www/html folder:
html
|favicon.ico
|index.html
|othersite.html
|background.png
|style.css

If I try to open the index.html directly, an error 404 is shown.
It should open the correct .html file but it only shows the 404 Page

Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.55 (Ubuntu) Server at example.com Port 443

Thanks for help
